# iTunes Connect Developer reject - Delete non needed build / binaries

Tags: user-interface, binary, app-store-connect

I uploaded a binary update to the new iTunesConnect, but had not submitted. I found a bug, and tried to remove the existing binary - could not find a way to do that. I then submitted for review but immediately rejected it. Still can't see a way to delete it and upload a new one. How do I upload my new version? OR how do I cancel my update and start a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete binaries that are uploaded. I had to developer reject couple of times and I had 6 of these binaries there. I selected one and then submittted for approval. There is no way to remove "non-needed" ones from this list

Comment: how did you "developer reject" your app?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to reject Binaries anymore, just change the BUILD number to something higher 1.1 or something like that. Leave the version number the same.

Then it will let you upload it and you can select it from the list to add to your submission.

It took me a while to figure out but it's actually a much better solution than all the rejecting nonsense.