# How to "developer reject" an app in iTunesConnect after the Sep 2014 changes

Tags: xcode5, app-store-connect

I uploaded a binary but before submitting it for review I realized that the Product Name in the Build Settings wasn't correct. I fixed the issue and tried to upload the binary again, but ran into the version 1.x already exists issue while doing that. So I thought I'd just submit this, manually reject it and upload the fixed one.

But with the latest changes in iTunesConnect, like a lot of other stuff, the option to reject my binary seems to be tactfully hidden or completely missing. How do I reject my binary in the latest (Sep 14) iTunesConnect dashboard? Or what's the new process to make such changes?

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766993/itunes-connect-developer-reject-delete-non-needed-build-binaries/25777209#25777209

Comment: @SamBudda I wonder where's the option for Developer reject?

Comment: Select your app and the very top of Versions section there is this line "You can edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review." Click on remove this version

Comment: @SamBudda - where exactly is this button. There is no button there.

Comment: @RubberDuck see my answer below

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete app Build in New iTunes Connect Site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683441/how-to-delete-app-build-in-new-itunes-connect-site)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how you developer reject.

**NOTE:** The assumption here is that you have successfully uploaded and submitted a binary to iTunes.

- Login to your iTunes account and make sure you are on the version of the app that you want to remove. In my case I had v5.1 already approved and I wan to reject v5.2
- Now click on the link that says **remove this version from review**
- After that scroll down and see the red circle that shows up next to your binary. Click that and remove your binary
- Now go back to your Xcode, bump up your build version and then upload a new binary to iTunes. If you don't bump up your version then you will get an error saying that the build already exists there. **NOTE:** There is no way to remove the old build version. If you developer reject multplie times then there will be multiple build versions there
- Select your new bumped up version and then click Save button and then Submit button.

See these screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, at least in my case, this link to remove the build is only visible 24h after you send it for review. Or this is a bug or Apple hates developers.

Comment: I concur, the link to remove the build becomes available after a few hours .. not sure how many.

Comment: @SamB When app is developer rejected, will that action remove it from MyApps list ? This would be nice workaround because currently there is no way to remove test apps from MyApps list.

Comment: Apple should sit a designer down with a programmer who is submitting and updating his app for the first time. If you know and can remember, it works fine. It still makes no sense to do it this way!

Answer (score 1):

For those who can't see the "remove this version from review" prompt as shown above, there is a bug in iTunesConnect that prevents this from sometimes displaying.  Further details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27797073/2537017

Answer (score 0):

To remove the binary associated, hover the mouse over the version of the build in the first page. A red button appears

[image]

Comment: That for me, is one of the biggest UX boo boos ever made by Apple. Down with their pretty designers.

Comment: btw, I rejected my binary from my iphone app. Fortunately, that hadn't been updated :)
I'll accept your answer after I've tried this once.

Comment: Yeah it took me a while to figure it

Comment: there is no removal sign on the binary after you send the app for review. This answer is not correct for the question.

Comment: Yes you cannot remove the binary, you can reject the association of the binary to the app. See the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Just download [ITC](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect/id376771144?mt=8) to your iOS device and operate there.

Comment: I just did that half an hour ago. Was about to post that as an answer for others in the same boat. Thanks still.

Comment: there is no way to delete a binary from there.

Comment: @RubberDuck, yes deleting a binary isn't possible.