# how to reject binary in new iOS iTunes Connect UI?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, itunes

I have uploaded an app to iTunes Connect but because of authorization, app has got rejected. Now i need to upload new binary so i have followed below steps as per the new iTunes Connect UI :

> 1. First You have to upload a binary again from Xcode or Application Loader. There is appear you last setup Build with Version number select it and upload again.
> 2. Then, wait for some processing time and open your iTunes Connect account. You can check your uploaded build in Prerelease tab
> 3. After processing finish In Build section Click on + button and select a correct binary that you have uploaded and save.
> 4. After that you may click on Submit for Review Button. And it may take some time for uploading on iTunes again

I have followed the same procedure for my problem and am getting the attached screen, but the problem is after click on "Submit for Review" Button my app is status is not changing and still "Rejected" with red bubble.

[image]

[image]

Can you please help me to upload my app with status "Waiting for Review" to the iTunes Connect?

Thanks alot!

Comment: You need to increase your build number and upload , you will find new build and you will be able to Submit for Review button. Did you try that?

Comment: Cheers!!! Can you share the solution

Comment: sure but not today.. my battery is 2 % only but really my answer will support to others.. have a good day:)

Comment: I have already answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788342/how-to-developer-reject-an-app-in-itunesconnect-after-the-sep-2014-changes/25808715#25808715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is my solution for the same problem:

Suppose if you have uploaded your app binary build and version with **1.0** before, which has got rejected unfortunately from iTunes Connect. So, for upload the new binary.. you don't need to change the binary and App version, it should be **1.0**. Once you will submit the new binary from **XCode** or **Application Loader**, it will automatically update in your **iTunes Connect** **Prerelease tab** as below screenshot.

[image]

> - Now, you need to go to the **Build tab** (you can find in the bottom of the **new UI** **iTunes Connect** screen), there you can get your current uploaded binary.
> - Click on plus (**+**) button to select your binary and **SAVE** this build. After this, you will get one button "**SUBMIT YOUR REVIEW**" on your top of the **iTunes Connect** screen.
> - Just tap here and your new binary will upload to the **iTunes Connect** with status "**Waiting For Review**".

Thanks to all, please feel free to ask for any clarification regarding the same.

Good luck!