# How to remove app that is preparing for submission - iOS 8

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, form-submit

I am trying to submit an app for review on apple. I have accidentally started preparing two apps for submission. I would like to remove this. Does anyone know how?
[image]
These are the apps that I submitted. I would like to delete them.

Sorry. I wasn't specific enough last time. I have made an app. I began to try to submit the application, but I began doing it wrong. I started a new one, but that is wrong, too. The 'developer reject' idea was helpful until I remembered that both apps are version 1.

Note: They are both different 
applications; I want to delete both of them.

Does anyone know how to delete them, or should I just rename them randomly and forget they ever existed?

Comment: You can't delete your duplicate app in this case because it hasn't been approved for sale yet. But you can reject it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21465252/2274694

Answer (score 0):

You can developer reject your duplicate app that is waiting for review and after that you can [delete](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) it from your iTunes connect account.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you can reject your own app from the review process. Follow this link for help with that: [Click here for how to reject your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788342/how-to-developer-reject-an-app-in-itunesconnect-after-the-sep-2014-changes) To be able to delete these apps they first need to be approved for sale. So in this case, you can't delete your app(s) because it has not been approved for sale yet. [Click here for more info on deleting your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21465252/2274694)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/72383) you can do the following:

In iTunes Connect, select manage apps, then select your app. On the left side, there is a menu, select the button that says 1.0 waiting for review. Then select something to the extent of rejecting this version. Another simple way to do this is to download the iTunes Connect app. Then under products select your app, then select the status. Then tap rejects this binary.